# Ajax прямой url запроса

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, ajax, javascript

есть простой запрос, который нормально работает. (колбек функция срабатывает)

```
    var url = 'data.html';

    $.ajax({

        url: url,             // указываем URL и
        dataType : "html",   
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) { // вешаем свой обработчик на функцию success
            alert(textStatus);
        }

    });
}
```

Но стоит поменять url на что-то типа http://ajax.com/data.html и сразу запрос перестаёт работать. (срабатывает error). При этом всём, если попытаться отправить данные на этот url, то данные нормально отправляются, но получить ничего кроме error по внешней ссылке не выходит. Ссылка работоспособная, я проверял. В чём проблема - я не могу понять. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким случаем?

Comment: Начните отсюда: [Правило ограничения домена](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_ограничения_домена)

Comment: И продолжите здесь: [JSONP][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP